# VBScript count new lines

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for a function on how to count how many new lines there are in a particular string that is being returned from the DB.

I've seen functions to do this JavaScript and PHP but none for VBScript.

I want to first check if there are Carriage Returns in the string (and count them), then I want to do a replace on them to a `<br/>` tag.

I suppose I could do the replace on vbCrLf and if it doesn't find one then there will probably be no harm done.  However, for debugging purposes right now I would really like to get the count so I know what it is doing (and if it is what I'm expecting).

Any ideas on how to do this in VBScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to split the string and see the [UBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the array:

```
'Split the stringfile into lines
arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)

lineNb = UBound(arrLines)
```

code adapted from [here](http://hacktivision.com/index.php/2009/04/24/vbscript-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-lin?blog=2)

Comment: +1 I like, plus to get the end result with `<br/>` tags you could simply do a `Join(arrLines, "<br/>")`

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegExp, if you want the Count **and** the replacement:

```
>> s = Join( Array( 1, 2, 3 ), vbCrLf )
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = vbCrLf
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute( s ).Count
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace( s, "<br />" )
>>
2
1<br />2<br />3
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing the string and only need to know how many replacements, how about:

```
s = StringFromDB
l = Len(s)
s = Replace(s,vbCrLf,"<br/>")

MsgBox "Replaced: " & (Len(s)-l)/3
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I read that for new lines chars is possible to use:

```
Cr   (Carriage return)
Lf   (Line feed)
CrLf (Both of the previous)
```

They are OS system related / specific: for what I know **vbCrLf** works in win systems platforms only, while other in linux/unix/mac OSs.

I suppose that will be better for a more general approach the use of vbNewLine instead of vbCrLf because vbNewLine adapts to the correct way as needed.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, because I am not totally sure about.
tnx